# How to get rtp(javacv ffmpeg) stream from VLC as client

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, vlc, rtp, javacv

I am trying to play rtp stream from vlc player which I created using javacv. Here is the code:

```
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtsp://10.6.0.147:554/ufirststream");
        frameGrabber.start();  // First I take another stream 

        FFmpegFrameRecorder frameRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("rtp://239.31.31.69:4433", frameGrabber.getImageWidth(), frameGrabber.getImageHeight());

        frameRecorder.setFormat("rtp");
        frameRecorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        frameRecorder.setVideoCodec(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO); <-- AV_CODEC_ID_H264
        frameRecorder.setFrameRate(25);           
        frameRecorder.setVideoBitrate(1024); <--1024*1024*2            
        frameRecorder.start();
        while (true) {
            frameRecorder.record(frameGrabber.grab()); //grab from stream, stream with rtp
        }
```

If I choose my codec as AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO I can play the stream from VLC using rtp://239.31.31.69:4433 with open network.

If I increase the quality using setVideoBitrate(1024*1024*2) the stream lags too much and if I decrease the quality is so bad.

I want to use AV_CODEC_ID_H264 as my codec to fasten things with better quality but i can't play the stream from VLC getting error :

> SDP required A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP stream. Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload format (96).

I tried to get sdp using wireshark and then I realized rtp stream doesn't have sdp :) so I tried to create my own sdp like this

```
c=IN IP4 239.31.31.69
m=video 4433 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

and this

```
v=0
c=IN IP4 239.31.31.69
a=recvonly
t=0 0
m=video 4433 RTP/AVP 99
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42c01e;sprop-parameter sets=Z0LAHukBQHsg,aM4G4g==;
```

but both seems to fail similar to this

```
> core debug: adding item `asf.sdp' ( file:///C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp )
core debug: processing request item: asf.sdp, node: null, skip: 0
core debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
core debug: rebuild done - 7 items, index 6
core debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
core debug: resyncing on asf.sdp
core debug: asf.sdp is at 6
core debug: creating new input thread
core debug: Creating an input for 'asf.sdp'
core debug: Creating an input for 'asf.sdp'
core debug: requesting art for asf.sdp
core debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Local\Temp'
core debug: `file:///C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp' gives access `file' demux `' path `/C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp'
core debug: specified demux `any'
core debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp' file='C:\Users\Sezer\Desktop\asf.sdp'
core debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 12 candidates
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
core debug: no access_demux modules matched
core debug: creating access 'file' location='/C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp', path='C:\Users\Sezer\Desktop\asf.sdp'
core debug: looking for access module matching "file": 21 candidates
filesystem debug: opening file `C:\Users\Sezer\Desktop\asf.sdp'
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
core debug: using access module "filesystem"
core debug: Using stream method for AStream*
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
core debug: starting pre-buffering
core debug: received first data after 0 ms
core debug: pre-buffering done 193 bytes in 0s - 188476 KiB/s
core debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 6 candidates
core debug: no stream_filter modules matched
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 6 candidates
core debug: using stream_filter module "record"
core debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp' file='C:\Users\Sezer\Desktop\asf.sdp'
core debug: looking for demux module matching "any": 65 candidates
live555 debug: version 2014.07.25
live555 debug: RTP subsession 'video/H264'
core debug: selecting program id=0
core debug: adding item `file.sdp' ( file:///C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/file.sdp )
live555 debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
live555 debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
core debug: using demux module "live555"
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: looking for a subtitle file in C:\Users\Sezer\Desktop\
core debug: searching art for asf.sdp
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
core debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 43 candidates
avcodec debug: CPU flags: 0x010053db
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
avcodec debug: trying to use direct rendering
avcodec debug: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
avcodec warning: threaded frame decoding is not compatible with DXVA2, disabled
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
core debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
core debug: Creating an input for 'file.sdp'
avcodec debug: avcodec codec (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) started
avcodec debug: using slice thread mode with 4 threads
core debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
core debug: looking for packetizer module matching "any": 23 candidates
core debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_h264"
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
core debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: searching art for asf.sdp
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
core debug: no meta reader modules matched
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
core debug: `file:///C:/Users/Sezer/Desktop/asf.sdp' successfully opened
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
core debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for asf.sdp
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: searching art for file.sdp
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for asf.sdp
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for asf.sdp
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for asf.sdp
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for file.sdp
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Sezer\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for file.sdp
```

Can you lead me to the right direction ? What should I do to get fair quality and no lag using rtp ?